# How to approach implementing an interface in a TDD way

Tags: testing, tdd, bdd, fuse

So I'm trying to convert myself to a more test- and behaviour- driven approach to my development.  It's good for me, and I've seen good results in the few projects I've used it for so far.

My current project is a FUSE-based filesystem - I want to add some functionality over basic filesystem access so FUSE seemed like a good fit.  All I really need to do is implement a set of functions that fit the appropriate interface, wrap it up appropriately, and go.

However, test first, I remind myself.  I've already written a set of cucumber features to lay out the basic expectations of how the overall app should work, so now it's time to get down to testing the innards.

Now, I could just write unit tests for each of the functions I need to write for the interface, and then get to coding the interface - but that doesn't seem overly test-*driven* to me.  Sure the tests exist, but the interface is really what's driving things.

Am I going about this wrong?  Or am I expecting too much?

Give me a "what-what" in the comments if you think this should be community wiki - I can't even decide if this *has* a right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1.  What is one thing the interface **must** do?  One thing.

Step 2.  How will you prove it does that one thing?

Step 3.  Write a test to prove the interface really does that one thing.

Step 4.  Run the test -- it will fail.  You haven't actually written the interface.

Step 5.  Code the interface.

Step 6.  The test will pass.

Move on to the next thing the interface **must** do.

This has little to do with the functions you've already designed.  This is totally focused on externally visible feature the interface **must** have.  It may turn out that your functions are the right thing.  Or it may turn out that you over-engineered these functions.  Or under-engineered them.  The point is to drive your design from the things a component **must** do and the tests to prove what it must do.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's only focused on Ruby, [The rspec book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) has a good introduction on the BDD cycle.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add some functionality over basic filesystem access so FUSE seemed like a good fit

It is hard to develop fuse fs. Two main problems is VERY hard debugging and multi-threading. Also I had (and now have) problems with testing my fs. Maybe [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) will satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I'm having pretty good luck using [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) to test my fuse callbacks one by one (with my mocked `fuse_get_context()`).